# Accented letters in source blocks in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I am having issues getting org-babel to export accented letters properly. This happens only in source blocks. For

```
#+BEGIN_SRC java
// Testing characters á, é, í, ó, ú, ç, ã
public void test(){}
#+END_SRC
```

The resulting export will exclude these characters. If I use them outside of source blocks everything works as expected.

Any help here is appreciated!

**EDIT**
This only happens in the PDF export. The generated text file contains `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` which should work.

Comment: What format are you exporting to?  I tried it and it works fine with html and text.  With latex output, the characters are put into the tex file, but they don't show up in the final output.  If your setup is similar, I'd imagine the problem lies with the latex configuration.

Comment: It works fine for me, including pdf. The character encoding used (variable `buffer-file-coding-system`) may be of interest.  If the problem is with the pdf, check the character encoding of the latex file matches the `\usepackage[xxx]{inputenc}` in the file.

Comment: Yes, the problem is only with the pdf export. Didn't notice it until now. I have \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} in text file (this should cover my case if I am not mistaken).